# Grails 2.0.0.M2 - cascade save problem

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have two simple domain classes:

```
class Name {
 String firstName
 String lastName

 static belongsTo = [person: Person]
}

class Person {
  Name name
  String comment
}
```

and service with two methods:

```
class PersonService {
  Person newPerson() {
    def person = new Person()
    person.name = new Name()
    person
  }
  Person savePerson(Person person) {
    person.save()
  }
}
```

Now if I create a new `Person` with `PersonService.newPerson()` and then try to save it using `savePerson()` method using grails 1.3.7 everything works fine. With grails 1.4.0 or 2.0.0.M2 exception is thrown

> Column 'name_id' cannot be null

Is this a bug in new grails? Or maybe there is something wrong with my code?

Test method:

```
void testPersonSave() {
    def person = personService.newPerson()
    person.name.firstName = 'f'
    person.name.lastName = 'l'
    person.comment = 'comment'

    personService.savePerson(person) //throws an exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug. Please JIRA: http://jira.grails.org/ .