# Saving a reference through belongsTo

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I'm making a script using some already created (not by me) domain classes from grails.

```
class Person extends OAP {
  static hasMany = [addresses: Address]
(...)
}

class Address {
  static belongsTo = [oap: OAP]
(...)
}
```

class OAP has no reference to Address.

So I was trying to do:

```
p.save()
a.oap = p
println a.oap
a.save()
```

with p being Person and a being Address, but although it prints the correct person on the console, the reference is not saved on the address table (oap_id stays null)

P.S.: It may not be the best relationship set-up in grails, but that's what I have to work with

Comment: try to remove the first `p.save()` and also use `a.save(failOnError:true)` to see whether (and why) it is saved.

Answer (score 1):

Try `p.addToAddresses(a)` and then `p.save()`. It should save both `p` and `a`.
See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.2.4%20Sets,%20Lists%20and%20Maps

Comment: Which grails version do you use? 
There's a bug in grails 1.4.0.M1 and 2.0.0.M1/M2. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387745/grails-2-0-0-m2-cascade-save-problem)

It should work with grails 1.3.7

Comment: try with this p.save(flush:true), suggesstion expected

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how GORM will behave in this situation because you have essentially entered into this weird zone where you have a unidirectional `hasMany` on Person which results in a `SAVE-UPDATE` cascade behavior from Person and a `NONE` on Address.  Then you also have a unidirectional one-to-one between Person and OAP which results in an `ALL` cascade behavior on the OAP side, and a `NONE` on the Address side. So I'm not sure what to even expect here.  You need to fix the relationship to either:

- Make it so OAP and not Person `hasMany = [address:Address]`
- Make it so Address `belongsTo = [person:Person]`

Or, give some additional explanation as to what you're trying to do in your relationship and we can go from there.

Comment: try with this p.save(flush:true), suggesstion expected

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this, it resolved my problem

```
p.addToAddresses(a);
p.save(flush:true)
```